# Angular2 - Showing "Calculating,.." text till the Rendering of Observable Data is finished,

Tags: time, angular, observable, html-rendering

I've the following construct at the rendering side (html-template):

```
<span>   
    {{ (__reponseCalculation | async)?.grossPremiumPackage }} 
</span>
```

**Calculation takes up to 3 seconds.** During this time, I want to show the text **"Calculating,.."**

For this purpose I have a flag "calculationFinished", which hast to be set to true, after the rendering is finished.

How can I do that best?

Additional Information:

`__responseCalculation` is coming via:

`this.__reponseCalculation = this.__responseData
    .flatMap((data: any) => data.calculation);`

**Please consider:**

There is no subscribe function, the data is rendered over Elvis.Operator (?.) and has before an asyncron-pipe,..

The following approach is known to me and I'am not looking for it:

```
    this.__reponseCalculation = this.__responseData
        .flatMap((data: any) => data.calculation)
        .subscribe(
            (data:any) => this.__reponseCalculation = data,
            (error:any) => console.debug ('ERROR Calculation: ', error),
            () => {
                this.__flags.calculationReady = true;
            }
        );
```

E.g. Within template I want to send a "signal" to the "controller" (component), as far as the data rendering process is finished. Is it possible or is that a deadlock/impasse/..

Comment: Perhaps you can set a variable is_calculating in your controller class to false and turn it to true upon the async task has finished. Then use the hidden  atrribute to show the text based on the variable.

Comment: Thank you, but would you read the "please consider" section :)

Comment: Oops I did see that one but now I look at it more closely, I see that it is exactly what I proposed :).